# System.currentTimeMillis() vs Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now(UTC)).getTime()

Tags: java, time

Arn't both `System.currentTimeMillis() vs Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now(UTC)).getTime()` suppose to give same number, Try and find out that it doesn't.

What is the reason for this, Arn't both suppose to give same number ie no of milisec from 1970 ?

Comment: No. You should neither use `LocalDateTime` nor `Timestamp` for this. Not `LocalDateTime` because it doesn’t define a point in time, which you need for the millis. Not `Timestamp` because it’s poorly designed (a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `Date`) and long outdated. `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()` is another good option (see for example [Which one is recommended: Instant.now().toEpochMilli() or System.currentTimeMillis()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705657/which-one-is-recommended-instant-now-toepochmilli-or-system-currenttimemill)).

Answer (score 2):

If you **read the documentation**, the javadoc of [`Timestamp.valueOf​(LocalDateTime dateTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime)) says:

> The provided `LocalDateTime` is interpreted as the local date-time in the **local time zone**.

Since the `LocalDateTime` in the *UTC* time zone, not the *local* time zone, the result is a time zone shift to JVM's default time zone. If you remove `ZoneOffset.UTC` from the `now()` call, or use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` instead, it'll work as you expected.

Alternatively, if you do have a `LocalDateTime` in UTC, and want to convert to `Timestamp`, you need to say the `LocalDateTime` is in UTC:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(UTC); // cannot change time zone
long millis = Timestamp.from(ldt.atZone(UTC).toInstant()).getTime(); // so specify time zone
```

Of course, the values will still not necessarily be *equal*, since a few milliseconds of time may have passed between the two calls.